# getting Swift Object from Objective C class using another Swift File

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have been trying with no success the following structure:

**ClassA.swift**

```
class ClassA:NSObject{
   var varA = ""
}
```

then I have a **ClassB.h** and **ClassB.m** (Objective c) and I am not able to define "Project-Swift.h" in the .h file so i import it into the .m

```
@interface ClassB()
    @property ClassA *myClassA;
@end
```

and

```
@synthesize myClassA = theAClass;
```

The problem comes when I try

```
class ClassC:NSObject{
   let theClassAFromC = ClassB.myAClass
}
```

I get an error message **Value of type 'ClassB' has no member 'theClassA'**

Comment: have you created the bridging header..?

Comment: yes i did. that's why can access the objective c class, right?

Comment: Your first two steps are correct Swift -> Objc using Project - Swift .h file But in class C you are accessing Objc -> Swift  For that you need to create bridging header and import Class B There

Comment: thank you for the answer but I did that already. I the properties and methods are in the .h i have no problem but since I can't import Project-Swift.h i declare the property in the .m. It seems it is "private" and not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add your objc header to bridging header
2. In your objc header use **@class** notation for your swift class, e.g. *@class ClassA;*, instead of import "Project-Swift.h" file. You can import that one in your objc implementation file.
3. Don't forget that you cannot access non-static property of objc class the way you're declaring. Instead, initialize your *ClassB* object in your swift class and access it's property when needed. For instantiating the *ClassA* object you can use dependency injection in *ClassB*
4. As part of the convenience, use *@objc* declaration for your Swift classes accesible to objc runtime

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I wanted to know. Although I saw it somewhere i thought i could use the bridging file. The project has a lot of objective c code and it is good to update by parts.

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding ;)

Comment: One more thing. I have declared a ClassA property in Class B and when I try to implement any method in ClassB from ClassA I get the following message "Receiver type 'ClassA' for instance message is a forward declaration"

Comment: You've got to import the Swift's precompiled header in implementation file of your Class B -> "Project-Swift.h" - this way all declarations made on ClassA will be visible also to ClassB. If you've still got the problem, check the generated "Project-Swift.h" header and find declaration of ClassA. See if all properties/methods you try to accesss are available also to Objective-C counterpart.

Comment: It works! That's exactly what I needed! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

try to search with keyword `"Bridging-Header"` and then add

```
#import "ClassB.h"
```

**That does not work in my case.**

adding ClassB.h in my Bridge File makes properties from .h Visible But not the the properties in my .m file. If i add Class.m In my header file then Module-Swift.h is not found

Comment: That does not work. I am Declaring the property into .m file. If I add the .h into the Bridging-Header.h it is still not found. i tried an objective c project and if import classB.m the it founds the property but not the Project-Swift.h